# What is the shortcut to set filetags?

Tags: org-mode, tags

In org-mode, when I press `C-c` `C-q` and I don't have a header anywhere but just have a filetags section defined:

```
#+FILETAGS:
```

then I get the error:

```
org-back-to-heading: Before first headline at position 52 in buffer CAPTURE-20200608211317-test5.org
```

What I would like is that I get the nice interactive tag selector popup and can set my filetags like that.

The only work-around is now to start a:

```
* headline
```

and store the tags there.

Comment: like `C-c C-q TAB` on a headline?

Comment: The interactive tag selector is based on completion from the tags existing *already* in the buffer. What do you expect it to show you in this case?

Comment: I have most used tags set in my .emacs file. I just thought I get the interactive thingy and it'll set the tags on the filetags.